# Verify password with Zend Auth?

Tags: zend-framework, authentication

Using the Zend Auth and AuthAdapter libraries, you can easily handle login actions with the `authenticate()` method. However, I'm trying to implement a "you must re-enter your password to update your profile" action.

If I use the `authenticate()` method and it fails, the user is fully logged out, and therefore loses permission to view the account editing form. Other than looking up the user's password information in the database manually, is there a "verify password" option within Zend Auth?

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer:

From the Zend Auth documentation:

> "When the automatic use of persistent storage is inappropriate for a particular use case, a developer may simply bypass the use of the Zend_Auth class, using an adapter class directly."

So, calling `Zend_Auth::getInstance()->authenticate($authAdapter);` results in the user's session being modified. Calling instead `$authAdapter->authenticate();` does not modify the user's session, but still returns a `Zend_Auth_Result` object such that you can check the `isValid()` method.

Comment: Stackoverflow makes me wait for a few days before I can accept my own answer. Glad to increase the general knowledge, though!